# Disable Offline Files (mobsync.exe) on Windows 7 Home

Tags: windows-7, performance, sync, offline-files

This morning I was watching the CPU graph of a Windows 7 Home laptop and noticed that every few seconds, the CPU would spike several percent. I watched the processes and determined that it was `mobsync.exe` (Offline Files) that was the culprit.

I tried the usual steps that Googling turns up, and clicking the *Manage Offline Files* link to bring up the *Offline Files* dialog to click *Disable Synch* does not work because the dialog will not display. This makes sense since everything I have read indicates that Offline Files is not even included/supported in the Home version, so I am at a loss as to why it is running at all, let alone why it is sucking up CPU cycles. It seems that pressing <kbd>Win+X</kbd> to access the Mobility Center launches the process even though the function is not even available (and thus not useful) in the Home edition.

The two *Offline Files* services (`csc` and `cscservice`) do not exist on a Home edition system, so disabling them won't work. I also tried manually opening the *Offline Files* dialog with the command `rundll32.exe Shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL cscui.dll`, but just like clicking the link in the Control Panel, it does nothing.

Of course I can just kill `mobsync`, but it just runs again whenever the Mobility Center is opened (and possibly other times).

Perhaps a future update will stop a non-functioning/applicable feature from running unnecessarily and using up resources, but in the meantime, how can it be properly disabled (of course the Group Policy editor is not available on a Home version). Some people suggest hacking it by removing execute permissions from the file which should work, but is ugly and certainly not ideal.

Comment: [Ho To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/8668/what-is-mobsync.exe-and-why-is-it-running/) has a solution for this have you tried that?

Comment: @avrik, like I said, the *Offline Files* dialog is not available in Home, and the article you linked to says right at the beginning: *Note: This process disables the Offline Files feature which is not available in Home versions of Vista or Windows 7*.

Comment: Check your Windows Services for "Offline Files", disable the service, then restart the PC.

Comment: "If you have a home version of Vista or Windows 7, you will see mobsync.exe running in task manager, but closing out of Sync Center should stop the process. If you were using Sync Center and ActiveSync to manage a mobile device and no longer need it, you can uninstall ActiveSync software and it should stop mobsync.exe as well."

Comment: @Moab, 7 Home does not have an Offline Files service and I cannot find ActiveSync. This laptop does not use any sort of sync (in fact, nothing even shows up in the Sync window because it has nothing to sync with). Offline Files should not even be available in Home, yet `mobsync` runs whenever `Win+X` is pressed. Seems like Microsoft's left hand doesn't know what its right hand is doing.

Comment: You will have to use process monitor to find out what is calling mobsync to load.

Comment: It's the Mobility Center (`Win+X`). Like I said, Offline Files are not supposed to included in Home (and are clearly not supported, which is why the dialog does not open), yet *part* of the function is still included and runs (and of course does nothing since the rest of the functionality is not available).

Comment: I found this [Tool](http://reliancepc.com/menu/tips/mobsync/) from [Microsoft](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-windows_programs/disable-mobsync/55aacc06-dcb9-4cba-ae91-fd79857a2b41). The user is using the `Vista Home Premium` hope it will help you to achieve the task you want to.

Comment: @avirk, thanks a lot. I’ll test the program tomorrow. (It looks like others have been baffled by this contradictory behavior and that person even made a whole page and several tools to address it.)

Comment: I'll be happy to hear if it helps you. Best of luck.

Comment: I'm just curious to know that does that tools helped you or not?

Comment: It’s the weekend here; I’ll test it the next time I have access to that system (probably Monday EST).   Cheers.

Comment: During the weekend, I examine the contents of the file and it is basically a collection of scripts and executable files that essentially just remove the execute permission of `mobsync.exe`. I've seen this trick mentioned on some of the pages where people have asked about disabling that file. I've seen mentions of setting a registry entry or disabling a some services either don't work or do not even apply to the Windows 7 Home. I'll see if one of those will work because hacking it with permissions is not ideal (the program still tries to run, but fails, with whatever side-effects that causes).